# What is linear directional effect?

Tags: vectors, terminology, definition

A vectors are those quantity which have magnitude as well as direction. The vectors associated with a [linear directional effect](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=linear+directional+effect) are called polar vectors. What is linear directional effect?

Comment: I've never heard of the term.....

Answer (score 1):

According to the link, a linear directional effect is a physical thing that can be described by a polar vector: Force, velocity, electric field, and so on. Of course that answers circular with respect to the question, but that's it. It seems definitional, the only distinction is that one is a physical object and the other is a formal mathematical representation thereof.

Note that common vector equations in physics relate physical directional effects on both sides of the equation:

$$ \vec p = m\vec v $$
$$ \vec F = m\vec a $$
$$ \vec a = \frac{d\vec v}{dt} $$
$$ \vec F_E = q\vec E$$

and so on. That last one can be contrasted with:

$$ \vec F_M = q\vec v \times \vec B$$

The magnetic field cannot be described as a linear directional effect, and it must enter into the equation with a cross product to have a linear directional effect on the L.H.S.

Note: you can have a long and successful career as a physicist or engineer without ever considering the phrase "*linear direction effect*" again; however, should you chose the former, you had better understand the difference between polar and axial vectors.